# How to publish a blob file to GCP Pub/Sub?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

Currently, I'm using java to publish a message and data to pub/sub. I am wondering how to publish a blob file to pub/sub service?

```java
 @PostMapping(value = "/publish")
    public String publishMessage(@RequestBody MyAppGCPMessage message) {

        var attributes = singleFormatAttributes(message);
        var messagePub = PubsubMessage.newBuilder().putAllAttributes(attributes).build();
        repository.publish(messagePub);
        return "message published to google Pub/Sub successfully";
    }

    private Map<String, String> singleFormatAttributes(MyAppGCPMessage entity) {
        return Map.of(
            "id", entity.getId(),
            "name", entity.getName(),
            "email",entity.getEmailId()
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot publish a blob file to pub/sub. what you can do is upload the file to Cloud Storage and setup notification to your choice of pub/sub topic. Setup a Cloud Function to be triggered in response to the event. You will get the location of the uploaded file in the event data. Do whatever processing you want to do in the Cloud Function.

Comment: The message file is limited (10Mb max) and you pay for the message size!!